# Server-sent Events not working with Window App Service in Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, iisnode, azure-appservice

I've tried to get the following code running on a Windows App Service on Azure:

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {

  response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
  response.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
  response.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
  response.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
  response.flushHeaders();

  var interval = setInterval(function () {
      response.write("data: extra data\n\n");
  }, 1000);

  request.on('close', function () {
    clearInterval(interval);
  })
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
server.listen(port);

console.log("Server running at http://localhost:%d", port);
```

It works when I run it locally, however does not when deployed to the App Service.

My `web.config` looks like as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^app.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{PATH_INFO}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    
    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
    <iisnode flushResponse="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I've added in `<iisnode flushResponse="true" />` and `responseBufferLimit="0"` as per suggestions from the Microsoft App Service docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-nodejs-best-practices-and-troubleshoot-guide#flushresponse but still to no avail.

Comment: The core of this problem is to learn to troubleshoot. Please refer to my suggestion, the attributes that need to be modified, add and check step by step to the `web.config` file.

Comment: That may well be the case but I don't know how to troubleshoot this issue any further. Is there a method to debug the web.config file? Is there a working example of Server-sent events example project you can refer me to where this is working?

Answer (score 0):

Your project can run locally, that is, through the command line `npm start`, `npm run dev`, etc. to start webapp in local. At this time, the `web.config` file will not be used. Unless you deploy the project in the local `IIS`, `IIS` will recognize the `web.config` file.

Assuming that there is no problem with your project, I think you can delete your `web.config` file first (must be backed up). Then use git to deploy, and then through kudu, find the `web.config` automatically generated by the deployment (also needs to be backed up, because subsequent operations will modify the source file, if the modification is wrong, you can restore it).

[A post about git deployment to automatically generate web.config.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63983932/azure-web-app-getting-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page/63985336#63985336)

1. Compare the difference between the `web.config` content in your current project and the automatically generated git deployment, and add the functions and content you want, such as `flushResponse="true"`,`responseBufferLimit="0"`.
2. If something goes wrong, remember to restore the backup file. This can be used for troubleshooting.

Comment: the ```web.config``` file was automatically generated when I deployed the app originally then I modified it to look like the above. I've changed the web.config file before to an invalid syntax and it's caused a 500 error so I know it's trying to read it.