# Azure web app and Azure ad http error 500.79 Internal server error

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I created my azure web-app and created app registration. and connected Azure AD to my web app. I used express security and I also used advance security with client ID and client secret. I know there is a similar question about this error. but it is not clear answer.

Most likely causes:

- IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
- IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
- IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
- The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
- The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

Things you can try:

- Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
- Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
- Verify the permissions for the DLL.
- Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
- Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I know that the problem is most likely due to the lack of `web.config` file.

**Solution:**

1. It is recommended to ensure that your project can run normally locally.
2. [Continuous deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment) is recommended

At present, the reason for your problem is the lack of `web.config`, which will be automatically created when using git deployment. As shown below.

[image]

For more details, you can check my answer in another post.

[**Azure Web App getting “You do not have permission to view this directory or page.” when launch app**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63983932/azure-web-app-getting-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page/63985336#63985336)

Comment: But I am not using github. I add my code via filezilla. FTP connection. from get publish url. Because of this there is nothing inside development center. also there is a webconfig file inside the code.

Comment: @newUser Then I suggest you execute a command similar to `npm run build` to upload the contents of the dist or build folder using FTP.

Comment: @newUser I can help you solve the issue, you just make sure you can run successfully in local.

Comment: my code is running successfully because I used it in another project. it is php code.

Comment: Is the webapp in question being deployed now from node or php?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224134/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-newuser).