# I got 403 error after deploying Next js Full Stack Application Azure Web Apps "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Tags: next.js, deployment, azure-web-app-service, http-status-code-403

I created a Full Stack application using Next.js with Typescript, and deployed it successfully to Azure Web Apps using GitHub, however when I try to access the website I got the message "You do not have permission to view this directory or page.".

I already run "npm run build" and test the application locally to make sure everything is working, I also verified the Default documents to include index.js, index.tsx, index.html, and there are not IP restrictions or authentication requirements. The Virtual Path is set to / and the physical path is set to site\wwwroot.
I tried adding a web.config file with details about serving the website (as I understand there is not need for this file, but I tried), but it didn't work either, I got the same message.
Then I start over and deployed it from VS Code to see what happens, but I got the same error.
I already checked the files in Azure Web App console and all files are there.
I do not know what else to try, I really need help.

[KUDU Console site folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSGEq.png)

[wwwroot folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3un6i.png)

[error on Log Stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdPKi.png)

[Default documents in Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w04Se.png)

Answer (score 0):

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

This error occurs if there is any missing files/ misconfiguration.

***Check if the below steps help to fix your issue:***

- Try accessing your website by adding `/` to the URL/default domain.
  i.e., `https://pravuwebapp.azurewebsites.net/`
- Check if all the files of your application deployed properly. This can be checked in App Service=>Advanced Tools=>Kudu Site=>Debug Console=>CMD.

[image]

- Make sure your files are deployed to `wwwroot/` folder.
- Add the settings `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true` and `WEBSITES_PORT=<port_number_of_your_application>` in App Service=>Settings=>Configuration=>Add New Application Settings.
- Go to App service=> Monitoring=> App Service Logs=> Select Filesystem.

[image]

- Now you will be able to figure out the exact cause in the error logs in `Logstream`.
- And also, you can check the error logs in Diagonostic settings of App service.
- If this doesn't help, try deploying your application to *Linux web app*.

***References:***

[SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853599/how-to-debug-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page), [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63983932/azure-web-app-getting-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page)

Comment: Hello Pravallika, I did everything you mentioned, but it's still not working. I created a simple test application and deployed in Azure Web Apps to try, and it doesn't work either. I posted some images in the original post so you can guide me about what else I can try.

Comment: Can you check if you have `web.config` in the deployed files under `site/wwwroot`?

Comment: I checked and I do not have it, neither server.js nor app.js. Since it is a Next app, do I need a web.config file?

Comment: Refer the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54908662/unable-to-deploy-next-js-to-azure/54942593#) solutions which may help to fix your issue.